# Anyway to include another maven project on my local filesystem as a dependency?

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven 'project A' that depends on another open source artifact available in the Maven repo. However, I have downloaded the code of that artifact to my local disk and made modifications to it's code which I want in my project A. Is there any way I can link these two such that when project A is built the jar for the artifact is also built from my local disk without including this artifact into a parent pom? Basically I don't need a parent pom because in the final build I will be contributing this code back to the open source project and just referring to the project via a dependency in my pom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy to share a project within a machine.
Here is the generic answer.

1. Create project A and B
2. Assume project A depends on B
3. Install project B locally ( mvn install )
4. Declare a dependency for B in A

```html
<dependency>
     <groupId>mygrp</groupId>
     <artifactId>B</artifactId>
     <version>use-the-right-version</version>
</dependency>
```

5. Now project A will resolve dependency B.
6. Eclipse will work properly as well
7. If you import project B into eclipse, it will automatically become a source-dependency for the project.

In your case the opensource project is "project B".
Just do a "mvn install " on the opensource project.

The opensource project is already declared as a dependency.
It will be available for your project ( project A )

You can import both of them into eclipse, then you can edit them simultaneously.

Comment: yes one can install the project in local repo but then each time I make code changes I have to build the jar right? Anyway it is a trivial problem with gradle which I am using right now. IntelliJ seamlessly manages both projects without me having to do a mvn install for each changes in the artifact

Comment: you can import both projects into IDEs (eclipse, IDEA, netbeans). Once they are inside the IDE, the dependency acts like a source dependency. Btw, this feature works the same in all IDEs. Mixing gradle and maven may be an issue in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I have misunderstood you, it sounds to me like you want to use a multi-module maven project:

http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html

You would use a parent POM like this to build the modules:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                         http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>your.groudId</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>Multi Module Simple Parent Project</name>
    <modules>
        <module>open-source-project-modified</module>
        <module>project-a</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

This will build `open-source-project-modified` first (your modified version on local disk), followed by `project-a` (also on local disk and dependent on the open source modified project). **The order of the modules in the POM should be in terms of dependencies.**

The structure of your project on disk would be:

```
simple-parent/
|_____pom.xml (the POM listed above)
|_____open-source-project-modified/
|_____project-a/
```

If you look in the introduction section of the link I provided, there is an examples zip file you can download:

http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/mvnex-examples.zip

In the zip file, go to *mvnexbook-examples-1.0/ch-multi/simple-parent* and you will find this very structure.

Comment: This is the best answer, especially if you want to modify both at the same time, commit them to the same repository and build them both on the build server.

Answer (score 0):

Execute `mvn install` on the opensource project to package and install on your local repo. After that you can add the dependency to your project A.